# Get max/min value from json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

Im am trying to get the min and max temp value from a json src. I'm not getting the desired result that I am looking for. This is what i have so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<?php  

$url = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$forecasts = json_decode($data); 
$length = count($forecasts->list);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $val = round($forecasts->list[$i]->main->temp, 0);
    }       

    $min = min($val);
    $max = max($val);

    echo "max: ". $max ." - min: ". $max;

?>
```

Comment: `$val` should be an array for this to work

Comment: PD of [php get MIN and MAX from loop results](//stackoverflow.com/q/21743259) or [Find maximum and minimum value in an array by the for loop](//stackoverflow.com/q/35306257)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `$val` in each pass through your `for` loop. What you actually want to do is push each value into an array that you can then take the min and max of:

```
$val = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $val[] = round($forecasts->list[$i]->main->temp, 0);
}       

$min = min($val);
$max = max($val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm assuming that "temp" is the attribute where you want to get min/max:

```
<?php

function max($list){
    $highest = $list[0]->main->temp;
    foreach($list as $l){
        $highest = $l->main->temp > $highest ? $l->main->temp : $highest;
    }
    return $highest;
}

function min($list){
    $lowest = $list[0]->main->temp;
    foreach($list as $l){
        $lowest = $l->main->temp < $lowest ? $l->main->temp : $highest;
    }
    return $lowest;
}

$url = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$forecasts = json_decode($data); 
$length = count($forecasts->list);    

$min = min($forecasts->list);
$max = max($forecasts->list);

echo "max: ". $max ." - min: ". $max;

?>
```

should be copy-pastable for your case...